# using templates in Code

Tags: bootstrap-4

So if I click on a button I want the value to change. In case that it is spanish i want to see 'Hola' and if it's english I want to see 'Hello'.

So my json files look as the following:

`es.json`

```
{
    "hello": "hola"
}
```

`en.json`

```
{
    "hello": "hello
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put a template like this somewhere in your code

```
    <ng-template #buttonTp>
      <span translate>hello</span>
    </ng-template>
```

and then in your field

```
<button [tooltip]="buttonTp" translate> hello </button>
```

Comment: yes because you are using the old version of ngbootstrap I guess. anyway I'm glad I could help you

Comment: I'm sorry it had to come to this